# In Angular, do we have a possibility to show different header colour based on the environment where the angular application is running?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTfXC.png)For example:
When I login dev environment: The header color of the application should be in Green
When I login dev2 environment: The header color of the application should be in Blue
When I login test environment: The header color of the application should be in Yellow
When I login prod environment: The header color of the application should be in Red

Any help?

Comment: ^ same method applies for earlier versions of angular

Comment: @AndrewAllen: I wanted to apply different color basically to differentiate each environment. Is it possible to specify in `environment.ts`?

Comment: Yep, sean has given the way if it's just one variable color to change. Anything more complex then I would recommend fileReplacements with  `styles.scss`, `styles.dev.scss`, `styles.dev2.scss` etc

Comment: @AndrewAllen: headerColor specified in environment.ts doesn't actually change the header color of the application.

Comment: You'll have to *use* the variable to set the color in the template

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an environment variable. Here is the documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/build#using-environment-specific-variables-in-your-app

```
// environment.ts (under the environments folder)
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  headerColor: 'green'
};

// environment.test.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  headerColor: 'blue'
};

// environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  headerColor: 'yellow'
};

// in a component
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

headerColor: string = environment.headerColor;
```

Comment: I tried the same way as above, but the header color doesn't change. Can you check the image which I have attached to the question?

Answer (score 0):

When you say header, I am assuming you simply mean a component that lives inside src. This should be quite simple to do:

1. Ensure that you have all of your different environments captured in the `/environments` folder, and that they also live inside angular-cli.json. You can also ensure that each environment object has a unique identifier.
2. Inside your component, you can import the environment object: `import {environment} from '../../*correct relative path*/environment'`
3. In your .scss file of the component, you can define multiple classes with the different background-colors as per the business logic you mentioned.
4. Create a getter variable in the .ts file, which has switch-case logic to return the correct class name depending on which environment you are in. For example:

```html
get headerClassPerEnvironment(): string {
  let class = "";
  switch (environment.uniqueIdentifier) {
    case ("dev"):
      class = "yellow-header";
      break;
    case ("staging"):
      class = "blue-header"
      break;
    case ("prod"):
      class = "whatever-header";
      break;
    default:
      class = "default-header";
  }
  
  return class;
}
```

5. Finally, in your .html file, you can add the multi-class binding to your HTML element, with the variable you created. For example, `<div [class]="headerClassPerEnvironment"> ... </div>`

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers.